# manipulating colSums output in R

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame, `y`, that looks like this:

```
y1<- c(1:5)
y2<- c(2:6)
y3<- c(3:7)
y<-data.frame(y1,y2,y3)
```

I then want to compute sum of each column in the dataframe, so I use `colSums` function.

```
colSums(y)
```

This returns two rows of data, with the column ID on top, and the sum of the column below. I can transpose this information using the `data.frame` function.

```
data.frame(colSums(y))
```

This returns a column of sample IDs, and a column of summed values. However, R treats it as a single vector. What I want is a vector that only contains the number values of the sums of each column.

Comment: `unname(colSums(y))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dumb question. All you need to do is enter

```
unname(colSums(y))
```

and you have it as a vector. Thanks to @LyzandeR

Comment: It's always a vector. It's a named vector by default, and an unnamed vector if you `unname` it.